# OpenCL - dynamic shared memory allocation

Tags: opencl, shared-memory

I am trying to translate some existing CUDA kernels to OpenCL and the problem is that I am bound to use OpenCL 1.2, so it is not possible to use [non-uniform work-group](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-20-non-uniform-work-groups) size, meaning that I should let `enqueueNDRangeKernel` decide local work-group size(to avoid non-divisible workgroup size w.r.t. global work size).

As it is mentioned [in this presentation](https://hpc-forge.cineca.it/files/CoursesDev/public/2017/Programming_paradigms_for_GPU_devices/Roma/Hybrid_OpenCL%202017.pdf), I use `__local int *` which is an argument of kernel function as shared memory pointer with the size that is defined in the host code using the `<Kernel>.setArg`.

In some of these CUDA kernels, I have allocated dynamic shared memory with the size that is dependant on Thread-Block or local workgroup size. When I try to translate these kernels to OpenCL, I don't know how to get local workgroup size that is set by `enqueueNDRangeKernel` passing a NULL value for the `local` argument to let it automatically decide local workgroup size.

To make it more clear, all I want is to translate this piece of CUDA code to OpenCL:

```
dim3 block_size, grid_size;
unsigned int smem_size;

block_size.x = 10;
block_size.y = 10;
block_size.z = 2;

// smem_size is depandant on ThreadBlock size.
smem_size = (block_size.x * block_size.y * block_size.z) * 5; 

myCudaKernel<<< grid_size, block_size, smem_size >>>(...);
```

*By the way, I need a general solution that is usable for 3-D workgroups as well.

*I have an Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: I think that's not possible, but am not sooo deeply familiar with that. Can't you compute a "suitable" local work size for your global size manually? (Of course, this may have odd corner cases - hoping that the global size is not a prime number, otherwise you'll have to introduce padding :-/). But maybe someone knows a proper/better solution.

Comment: Why not pass 10x10x2 as your local workgroup size? Then your code can hardcode the sizes and you can used fixed-size local memory. Just make sure the global size is a multiple of the local size. If your actual work is small than that, pass in the actual size and check if the global_id() is less than the actual size.

Comment: So I guess padding workgroup is the way to go, thank you guys